# Change not-allowed cursor on drag in React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

When I drag an image in react that has `draggable` set to true, I get `not-allowed` / `no-drop` cursor. I can't figure out how to target it with CSS to overwrite. The way I handle the drag is `onDragStart` then `onDragEnd`.

Comment: Would you mind showing some code so others could understand the problem?

Comment: Just created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cdn-b1xwm?file=/src/App.tsx) but couldn't reproduce the behaviour you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue back when I was working on one of my React projects, so I did some research and tested several methods that I found, but nothing worked for me. You see there is a property named `DataTransfer.effectAllowed` that specifies the effect that is allowed for drag operation, and there is a limitation to this API as you can read here -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/effectAllowed

Changing the styles or attaching an eventListener won't work, you have to use a different backend for this. Use `react-dnd` and `react-dnd-touch-backend` or `react-dnd-html5-backend` npm packages as a custom backend.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-touch-backend

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-html5-backend

Answer (score 0):

Without some reproducable code i just can try a shot in the dark: You have to call at the beginning of your drag handler `e.preventDefault();`.